# Python Quantlib convert Quantlib Date to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I have a list of dates defined in the Date format of quantlib. How can I convert these into datetime format. The reason I am asking is, that I would like to plot it and I received the follwoing error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Date'

when doing the following:

```
plt.plot(dates,rates, linewidth=2.0) # Without date plotting works out.
```

dates looks like the following:

```
[
  Date(11,12,2012), 
  Date(12,12,2012), 
  Date(13,12,2012),
  Date(14,12,2012), 
  Date(15,12,2012), 
  Date(16,12,2012),
  Date(17,12,2012), 
  Date(18,12,2012), 
  Date(19,12,2012),
  Date(20,12,2012)
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no predefined conversion, so you'll have to extract the information from the QuantLib date and use it to build a `datetime` instance. E.g., define something like

```
def ql_to_datetime(d):
    return datetime.datetime(d.year(), d.month(), d.dayOfMonth())
```

after which you can use `ql_to_datetime(d)` for a single date, or `[ ql_to_datetime(d) for d in dates ]` for a list. (You can also define another function taking a list, of course.)

**Update:** in recent versions of QuantLib-Python, a predefined conversion was added.  You can now say `d.to_date()` to convert a date, or `[d.to_date() for d in dates]` for a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is what I was looking for :).

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster way. Since `datetime.datetime` has methods `fromordinal()` and `toordinal()` to convert between `datetime.datetime` and an integer that represents the date. Similarly, `ql.Date` also has the method `serialNumber()` to convert `ql.Date` to integer and its constructor accepts the integer as well. However, `datetime.datetime` uses `0001-01-01` as 1 with increments in days while `ql.Date` uses `1899-12-31` as 0. Hence, to convert between the two, we can use the following function:

```py
def ql_to_datetime_new(d):
    return datetime.datetime.fromordinal(d.serialNumber() + 693594)
```

where `693594` is equal to `datetime.datetime(1899,12,31).toordinal()` - 1.
To test the speed, I also use the function from Luigi's answer:

```py
def ql_to_datetime(d):
    return datetime.datetime(d.year(), d.month(), d.dayOfMonth())
```

Then, test the speed as follows:

```
d = ql.Date(31, 12, 2000)
%timeit ql_to_datetime(d)
%timeit ql_to_datetime_new(d)
```

On my computer, the results are

```
796 ns ± 18.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
436 ns ± 0.938 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Hence, the one that I proposed is faster.